# libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, eclipse, python-imaging-library

I am trying to do some image processing with python and the PIL.  I was having a problem that I wouldn't correctly import the _imaging folder so I did a reinstall and now I am getting this problem:

```
libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I did apt-get remove python-imaging in the command line and then apt-get install python-imaging and now it won't work in Eclipse.  Any tips?

Comment: Most likely you are using other than Ubuntus default Python interpreter or you mess with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try installing the libjpeg62 module in Ubuntu, the libjpeg.so.62 file is a part of it.